# Question on rounding off rule

Tags: statistics, rational-numbers

There is a specific rule(Banker's Rule I think) for rounding of numbers that end in 5. The rule is that we add 1 to the preceding digit of it's odd but keep it as it is if it's even. It's always keeping it even.

Why is this rule applied? I read something like it is done to prevent biased rounding off our something.

Comment: Don't open [this can of worms again!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321859/why-do-we-generally-round-5s-up-instead-of-down/1200209#1200209)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we generally round 5's up instead of down?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321859/why-do-we-generally-round-5s-up-instead-of-down)

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) has a list of six different ways to round halves.  To see the logic of round to even, consider adding a long column of numbers that are all an exact number of tenths-that all have exactly one decimal place.  Now consider the effect of rounding to integers before adding.  If the decimals are evenly distributed, the increases in the ones with $.6, .7, .8, .9$ will be balanced by decreases in the ones with $.1, .2, .3, .4$.  If you round $.5$ up, as some have been taught to do, the sum will increase.  If you round to even, the sum will increase half the time and decrease half the time.